# partial static routing parameter angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, routes

Is it possible to use a partial-static parameter in angular 2 routing?
I'm going to explain:

Now I'm using classic parameter like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':type/fine.html',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: ':type/fine'
  }
```

But I would be able to use something like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: 'static-:type/fine.html',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo: 'static-:type/fine'
      }
```

To be able to redirect exactly to `static-{{parameterValue}}/fine`.

Is it possible?

Comment: You should look at https://angular.io/api/router/UrlMatcher. It allow to override the default matching strategy and provide your own. I think it may handle your case.

Comment: Just tried with that. The problem is that when the UrlMatcher tries to find `:type` parameter, it just sees that as a string, evaluating it exactly equal to ":type".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After many tries i've reached the knowledge that is impossible to do something like it. So i've implemented a completely different approach with a routing-guard following this example:

http://www.sparkbit.pl/angular-2-route-guards-real-life-example/

Just answering for anyone who will find same problem.

Comment: I believe this can be done with lazily loaded routed feature modules but it would be complex. Using guards seems like a solid alternative.

Comment: Already tried with lazy loaded modules but the problem is same: you can't match a partial static route. If you try you'll see that the only way to use a static&parametric routing path is to isolate a parameter between two `/` because angular sees a parameter only as a `folder path` or inside it.

Comment: I didn't realize that, that's a pretty serious limitation.